# C++ Template Specialization problem

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a syntax similar to this:

```
template <class P>
class Foo : public P
{
public:
    template <class T> Foo<P> & operator += (const T & v)
    { 
         /*grind*/
         return (*this);
    }
};
```

The problem starts when i try to specialize the `operator +=` (outside of `class Foo`) for a particular type (`int` for example). I could do this:

```
template <class P> Foo<P>& Foo<P>::operator += ( const int & v)
{...}
```

but partial specialization is not possible and it is practically impossible to know the type  of `P` at this point.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks,
Raxvan.

Comment: Why do you need to do it outside the class?

Comment: This would be simple if you would remove the requirement of having it outside the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the logic in the `operator+=`, put it in a helper class, this can be partially specialized as required.

Comment: That was my initial idea , but i ended up writing too much code. Thanks anyway but i think i have a solution. I just realized that i can move part of the functionality in the class P, removing the need for specialization.

Comment: Jollymorphic opened my mind , i was thinking too complicated. Helper class can work :)

Answer (score 1):

Node beat me to it, but here's some code that may help (though I'm using bare functions with overloading instead of a helper class):

```
template <class P>
class Foo : public P
{
public:
   template <class T> Foo<P> & operator += (const T & v)
   { 
      detail::implement_plus_equal( * this, v );
      return * this;
   }
};

namespace detail {
   template <class P>
   void implement_plus_equal(Foo<P> & f, int v)
   {
      /* grind an int */
   }

   template <class P, typename T>
   void implement_plus_equal(Foo<P> & f, T const & v)
   {
      /* grind a T */
   }
}
```

Comment: Gee thanks , i has something else in mind. This seems a nice solution also :).